# I don't understand the behaviour of this Rails template rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I have this controller:

```
class FormCreatorController
  def build_form
    if param[:ftype] == 2
       @partial_file = "extra"
    else
       @partial_file = "basic"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

This is called from a `new` view, where the code is like this:

```
<div class="column span-16 last">

    <%= form_tag build_form_ads_path,:method => :get,:remote => true,:id => "ad_builder_form" do %>

        <div class="column span-4">
            <strong>Form type</strong>
        </div>

        <div class="column span-12 last">
            <%= select_tag(:ad_type,options_for_select(@ad_types_mapped)) %>
        </div>
    <% end %>



    <div class="column span-16 last" id="myform">
        Please select an option
    </div>

</div>
```

I am using jQuery as my ajax framework.
The `myform` div, `ideally` should be replace with the contents of what's returned from the build_form. I have this in the `build_form.js.erb`:

```
$('#myform').html($('<%= render :partial => @partial_file %>'))
```

My basic form contains this:

```
<h1>Basic</h1>
```

My `extra` form contains this:

```
<h2>Extra</h2>
```

But, when the XHR request is made, nothing happens to my div. If, however, I put this in my partials:

```
$('#myform').html("<h1>Basic</h1>")
```

and

```
$("#myform").html("<h1>Car</h1>");
```

then they are correctly displayed in the page. Building custom forms using javascript string concatenation is tedious, but doable. I am sure there is a better way of doing things. What should I do so that the code from my partials is correctly rendered instead of my div?

EDIT: maybe it helps. This is the content of my application.js:

```
$().ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
        'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
        }
    });

    $("#ad_type").change(function() {
        $("#ad_builder_form").submit();
    });
});
```

Every time the value of the select changes, I'm submitting the form with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the html update:

```
'<%= escape_javascript(render "#{param[:ftype].eql?(2) ? 'extra' : 'basic' }") %>'
```

then update the element client side.

```
$("#ad_type").change(function() {
    $("#ad_builder_form").submit(function(){
     $('myform').html(this);
     });
});
```

or, to prevent problems with dynamically added html use jquery's live:

```
$('#ad_type').live('change', function() {
    action = $('#ad_builder_form').attr('action');
    $.post(action, jQuery.param(jQuery($('#ad_builder_form')).serializeArray()), function(data) {},
    'script');
    return false;
});
```

then return the script from your application as before:

```
$('#myform').html('<%= escape_javascript(render "#{param[:ftype].eql?(2) ? 'extra' : 'basic' }") %>'))
```

Comment: I still don't have the contents of the partials in the page. Maybe it helps to put the contents of my application.js as well. Check my edit.

Comment: If I understand correctly the form submission is incidental to the question. In response to an ajax request you're wanting to return a response of jquery page update of an html snippet. In firebug's console is the response correct, do you see the html? Also, is the #myform element existent (and occurring only once)?

Comment: I would like to replace the contents of the #myform div with one of the partials. In the console, I see this: `$('#myform').html('<h1>Basic<\/h1>\n'))` when doing a request for `basic`, and `$('#myform').html('<h1>Extra<\/h1>\n'))` for `extra`. However, I don't see a content-type returned. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Oh I see what it is, the script isn't being executed. Hold on I'll edit my answer.

Comment: So, I added the `live` in the application.js and the last snippet, with the `html` rendering of the partial in `build_form.js.erb` but I still don't have anything in the  div. The response returned in the firebug console remains the one I posted in the above comment.

Comment: Are you still using jquery's .submit() to send the form? If so then you'll need to evaluate its response - ie. $('myform').html(this); - as in former example of the two.

Comment: Isn't the submit happening in the `$.post` line, inside the `live`? How could I eval the response inside the `live`?

Comment: Oh if you are using $.post then no worries, I just wondered if you were still using submit. Can you stick an alert in your js.erb. file see if it's evaluated upon request.

Comment: Thank you! A million times thank you! Thanks to your comments and response I was able to make it work!

Comment: Cool! Feel free to edit my answer if some tweaking was required.